# Handling exceptions for functions with more than one argument?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function which has 2 arguments that are necessary and one that is optional.

I'm trying to account for all possible errors/exceptions and ensure that if these exceptions are raised I can exit my program "gracefully" e.g. print out a statement like "invalid filename".

So far, I've encountered NameError and TypeError, but I don't know how to account for these without using try and except. Notice in the code below, textfile1 must be a file and arg2 can be another text file or can be a string called 'listing'.

```
import os
def main(textfile1, arg2, normalize = False):
    if not os.path.isfile(textfile1): 
        print("Filename is invalid.")
        return None
    if TypeError:
        print("Missing 1 or 2 arguments. Make sure to enter both     arguments.")
        return None
    if NameError:
        print("Incorrect input. Enter argument with ' ' or " "")
    if arg2 != 'listing':
        if not os.path.isfile(arg2):
            print("Second filename is invalid")
    if arg2 == 'listing':
        #do something with the file
```

Clearly the use of "if" is wrong. I want to try handle exceptions like:

> NameError: name 'insert random name' is not defined
>
> TypeError: main() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'textfile1' and 'arg2'
>
> TypeError: main() missing 1 required positional argument: 'arg2'

Comment: way of handling exceptions is `try/catch`, also if conditions do not raise exceptions!

Comment: Can you please explain more why you don't want to use try/except statements? It looks suitable for me for your problem.

Comment: If you don't provide the required arguments to the call, the error is raised in the *caller*, not inside your function. If you get as far as the body of `main`, you can be absolutely sure that `textfile1` and `arg2` have *some* value assigned to them.

Comment: `NameError` is almost never something you catch; it indicates a bug you need to fix.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are trying to validate your arguments before trying to use them. That's fine, but typically this means *raising* exceptions for your caller to catch if there is a problem.

```
import os


def main(textfile1, arg2, normalize = False):
    if not os.path.isfile(textfile1): 
        raise FileNotFoundError(textfile1)
        # Or sys.exit(1) if you are sure that nobody calling you
        # can do anything sensible besides exit.

    # You won't even get this far if any required arguments
    # were omitted from the call.

    # If a NameError is raised, that means you have a bug to fix,
    # not a runtime condition to react to.

    if arg2 != 'listing':
        if not os.path.isfile(arg2):
            raise FileNotFoundError(textfile1)
    else:  # arg2 == 'listing' implied
        #do something with the file
```

Often, though, you simply try to use the arguments as they are, and catch any exceptions that may occur. If you don't have anything constructive to do once you've caught an exception, don't catch it in the first place.

```
def main(textfile1, arg2, normalize=False):

    try:
        with open(textfile1) as f:
            ...
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print(f"Could not find {textfile1} for reading", file=sys.stderr)
        return
```